# Не работает на телефоне гифка

Tags: img, gif

Вставлял через тег img

```html
<img src="my.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="">
```

На пк все отображается нормально, но с телефона захожу на сайт гифка делает 1 круг и пропадает. Обновляю появляется снова делает круг и пропадает 
Только что пересмотрел на сайт примерно через 1-2 секунды пропадают после загрузки. фон стоит на месте а картинки вставленные img пропадают сайт на вордпесс.
Проблема не в картинках а что связанное с ретиной к домену добавляется @2x и пытается там найти картинки как мне найти где это вообще происходит?

Comment: Покажите саму гифку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    var lowresImages = $('img');

    lowresImages.map(function(indx, elem) {
      var lowres = $(elem).attr('src');
      var highres = lowres.replace(".", "@2x.");
      $(elem).attr('src', highres);
    });
  }
```

нашел такой код. Он заменял ссылки и по этому не грузились фото